MUIを含むコンポーネントをJest&React Testing Libraryでテストする
表題でわからない事がありこちらにて質問させていただきました。
皆様のお知恵を借りれれば嬉しいです。React学習3ヶ月ほどです。
現在開発しているWebAppではMUIを用いておりますが、
Jestでのテストで以下のエラーが発生しており難航しています。
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')

質問 - 下記テスト方針は普遍的な手法なのでしょうか?
調べたところ、MUIを利用するとuseContextを裏側で使用しているが、テスト環境からの実行だとその依存関係が再現されずnull状態のcontextを参照しているため発生している問題のようです。
一応、それぞれのmuiコンポーネントをシンプルなHTMLタグに置換するモック化処理を入れればこのエラーは解消されるのですが、全てをモック化するには効率が悪いように感じます。
MUIコンポーネントを使ったテストはこの方針で行うのが一般的なのでしょうか?
例. テスト対象のモジュール
import React from "react";
import { Checkbox } from "@mui/material";

export default function CheckBoxComponent(){
    return(<Checkbox />);
}

例. テストコード内でモック処理(テスト結果 : PASS)
import React from "react";
import { render } from "@testing-library/react";
import CheckBoxComponent from "@/app/todo/components/test_CheckBox";

jest.mock("@mui/material",()=>({
    ...jest.requireActual("@mui/material"),
    Checkbox: (props)=>{
        return <svg {...props} data-testid="mock-checkbox">MockCheckBox</svg>
    },
}));

test("CheckBox renders correctly", () => {
    render(<CheckBoxComponent />);
});

例. テストコード内でMUI直接利用(テスト結果 : FAIL)
import CheckBoxComponent from "@/app/todo/components/test_CheckBox";

test("CheckBox renders correctly", () => {
    render(
            <CheckBoxComponent />
    );
});

試した事 - ThemeProvider
MUIのこのエラーはThemeProviderが存在しないため発生するとChatGPTから話があったので試しましたが同じエラーでした。
import React from "react";
import { render } from "@testing-library/react";
import { ThemeProvider, createTheme } from "@mui/material/styles";
import CheckBoxComponent from "@/app/todo/components/test_CheckBox";

test("CheckBox renders correctly", () => {
    const theme = createTheme();
    render(
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            <CheckBoxComponent />
        </ThemeProvider>
    );
});

実行環境 :
依存関係
review_with_nextjs@0.1.0 
├── @babel/core@7.26.0
├── @babel/preset-env@7.26.0
├── @babel/preset-react@7.26.3
├── @hookform/resolvers@3.9.1
├── @prisma/client@6.0.0
├── @testing-library/jest-dom@6.6.3
├── @testing-library/react@16.1.0
├── @testing-library/user-event@14.5.2
├── babel-jest@29.7.0
├── eslint-config-next@15.0.3
├── eslint@8.57.1
├── jest-environment-jsdom@29.7.0
├── jest@29.7.0
├── next@15.1.0
├── postcss@8.4.49
├── prisma@6.0.0
├── react-dom@18.3.1
├── react-hook-form@7.53.2
├── react@18.3.1
├── recoil@0.7.7
├── tailwindcss@3.4.15
└── yup@1.4.0

package.json
{
  "name": "review_with_nextjs",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.26.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.26.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.26.3",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^6.6.3",
    "@testing-library/react": "^16.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.5.2",
    "babel-jest": "^29.7.0",
    "eslint": "^8",
    "eslint-config-next": "15.0.3",
    "jest": "^29.7.0",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.7.0",
    "next": "^15.1.0",
    "postcss": "^8",
    "prisma": "^6.0.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@hookform/resolvers": "^3.9.1",
    "@prisma/client": "^6.0.0",
    "react": "^18.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.3.1",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.53.2",
    "recoil": "^0.7.7",
    "yup": "^1.4.0"
  }
}

jest.config.js
const nextJest = require('next/jest');

const createJestConfig = nextJest({
  dir: './', // プロジェクトのルートディレクトリ
});

const customJestConfig = {
  rootDir: './', // Jest が参照するルートディレクトリ
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/jest.setup.js'], // Jestのセットアップファイル
  testEnvironment: 'jest-environment-jsdom', // DOM環境でテストを実行
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$': 'babel-jest', // Jest内でのみBabelを使用
  },
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^@/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/$1', // "@/..." を src/ にマッピング
  },
};

module.exports = createJestConfig(customJestConfig);

next.config.mjs
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {};

export default nextConfig;

解決に必要な情報が足りなければ教えていただけると幸いです。
何卒よろしくお願いいたします。
